# Возможно ли сохранять в localStorage динамически добавляемые input, а после перезагрузки страницы возвращать их вместе с value?

Tags: javascript, form, input, localstorage

Представьте, что есть плюс нажимая на который вставляется `input`. Таких `input` можно вставить сколько угодно (пусть будет 30 штук). В эти `input` будет вводится временная информация, которая ежедневно в определенное время будет копироваться в `txt` файл по нажатию кнопки(это будет делать `php`, а не `js`).

Меня волнует могу ли реализовать сохранение в `localStorage` динамически добавляемые `input` + вносимую информацию, чтобы при перезагрузки страницы, все добавленное и записанное было восстановлено до того, как я очищу хранилище?

Меня так же интересует мнение по реализации этой затеи, или все же стоит найти другой путь. Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3):

В `localStorage` можно сохранить любую текстовую информацию (в пределах разрешенных объемов, конечно). Эти объемы измеряются мегабайтами, так что тридцать инпутов туда поместятся. Располагайте эти инпуты внутри одного родителя, тогда Вы сможете их сохранять и восстанавливать, используя `innerHTML` этого родителя.

Comment: Благодарю, информация была полезной!

Answer (score 3):

Реализовать такую задумку вполне возможно. Предлагаю для хранения введённых значений на форме использовать какой-то предопределённый ключ, а значением будет сериализованный массив, описывающий состояния полей ввода.

Вот пример. Запустить его можно на отдельном сайте.

```js
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Сохраняем значения в виде массива.
  var data = [];
  data.push(document.getElementById('t1').value);
  data.push(document.getElementById('t2').value);
  data.push(document.getElementById('t3').value);
  localStorage.setItem('k', JSON.stringify(data));
});
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Загружаем их, распаковывая сохранённый массив.
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('k'));
  document.getElementById('t1').value = data[0];
  document.getElementById('t2').value = data[1];
  document.getElementById('t3').value = data[2];
});
```

```html
<input id="t1"><br>
<input id="t2"><br>
<input id="t3"><br>
<button id="b">Save</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этой информации мне достаточно будет для реализации затеи